# PhpStorm showing code error for PHP method

Tags: phpstorm

I am curious as to why the following syntax is rejected by my PhpStorm editor:

[image]

PhpStorm version: 2016.1.2

Comment: Wrong (too low) PHP Language Level set up? Have you even tried hovering over the error to see the error description? It's also possible that your version does not support this syntax (it's an over 1 year old version) -- it will definitely work in latest version (considering the right language level was chosen, of course)

Comment: Error states: "Method should either have body or be abstract"

Comment: PHP Language level set to 7

Comment: Saving some dosh to upgrade :)

Comment: And it would seem the error is being invoked by the '?' before User with message "Unexpected Identifier".

Comment: AFAIK nullable types (`?User` from your example) are **PHP 7.1** feature... (which I do not think that your **2016.1.x** version supports) http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types

Comment: The code is handled without error in 2016.2.2. Perhaps it has something to do with the context in which your method is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nullable parameters/return types (`?User` from your example) is a [PHP 7.1 feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types).
2. `PHP Language Level` must be set to `7.1` in PhpStorm settings for this project (although right now it does not produce an error if language is set below 7.1 -- see [WI-32136](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32136) ticket).
3. Support for nullable types [was added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32002) in PhpStorm **2016.2.2** (which is newer than your 2016.1.x)

**Conclusion:** upgrade your PhpStorm to the latest version (which is 2017.2.1 at this moment). At very least you need to have PhpStorm 2016.2.2 for this particular syntax to be supported 9not showing an error).

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.